# Listview and Action bar TRANSPARENT in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in my activity and Action bar for activity set to transparent and UP navigation. Results are showing up properly but, the first item is showing up below actionBAR. Like the image below:

[image: Check Image Below]

Below is the code I am using to make the bar transparent:

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    setContentView(R.layout.invite_friends);
```

invite_friends.XML for listView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bluebackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/person_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Surprising that the listview is thinking it is full screen? How to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your xml for this activity?

Comment: If you are scrolling down I think is normal that behaviour

Comment: @jamesgates1 Updated my question with the XML code

Comment: @zozelfelfo I didn't understand can you please explain?

Comment: The tutorial is given here
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

You are telling the `ActionBar` to be in overlay mode, that means it will overlay the content instead of being at a fixed position above it. This is useful if you want to dynamically hide and show the `ActionBar` in your app, but it is not required to make the `ActionBar` transparent. Just remove it and it should work as you expect.

If you however want or need the `ActionBar` in overlay mode than you can just apply a padding to the content in your `Activity` which is equal to the `ActionBar` height. Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you are using the support library you have to use `?attr/actionBarSize` insted of `?android:attr/actionBarSize` like this:

```
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah just spotted this, seems like the culprit

Comment: If I remove the ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY.. My actionbar gets white color? I want it to be transparent?

Comment: That flag has nothing to do with the color. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I added android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" in my xml it is showing up properly now... THanks!

Comment: With this approach, in the case that you use the quick return pattern with the action bar (like the Google IO 2014 app) you will see an empty region in the ListView. The only way I have found for now is to use 2 different cell types in the ListView, being the cell in the first position an empty cell with the same height of the action bar.